# Android emulator and networking

Tags: android-emulator

Folks,

Environment: Windows 7

I have created an AVD for Android 2.3.3. When I launch this AVD from Android Virtual Device Manager UI, the networking does not seem to work. The browser does not connect to any website. However, if I run the emulator from the command line with dns-server option, it seems to work:

emulator -avd My23AVD -dns-server nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn

Why is this option required? Shouldn't it just work out of the box?

If it is indeed required, why doesn't Android Virtual Device Manager UI provide this option? I prefer using the UI instead of command line.

It appears the AVDs are kept in C:\Users\Peter.android\avd directory. I tried to trick the device manager UI by editing My23AVD.ini and adding dns-server=nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn line in it but this didn't seem to work either.

If I have no choice but to use the command line program, how to I specify "start-from-snapshot" and "save-to-snapshot" options? When I run "emulator -help" it talks about -auto-start and -auto-save options but the command line emulator does not recognize these options.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After doing some research, it appears that the emulator does not know which dns server to use if you have multiple LAN interfaces. In my case, I have a couple of extra pseudo interfaces as I am running VMWare workstation as well.

The emulator needs to be informed on the right dns server to use.

Unfortunately, the UI does not have an option to specify the dns server. You have to use command line to launch the emulator.

It also appears "-auto-start" and "-auto-save" are default options. No need for any extra parameters on the command line.

Hope this helps others.

Regards,
Peter